# Hide navbar while ajax loader loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm using ajax loader to hide my page until it loads everything. The problem is, for some reason it doesn't hide my navbar as you can see on the picture below. I want it to hide everything, include the navbar aswell.

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-transparent navbar-absolute fixed-top ">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="navbar-wrapper">

          </div>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" aria-controls="navigation-index" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end">
            <form class="navbar-form">
              <div class="input-group no-border">
                <input type="text"  class="form-control" placeholder="Search..." id="myFilter" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" onkeyup="myFunction()">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-white btn-round btn-just-icon">
                  <i class="material-icons">search</i>
                  <div class="ripple-container"></div>
                </button>
              </div>
              <p id="notfound">Not found!</p>
            </form>
            <ul class="navbar-nav">

            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>

<!-- loader -->
   <div id="ftco-loader" class="show fullscreen"><svg class="circular" width="48px" height="48px"><circle class="path-bg" cx="24" cy="24" r="22" fill="none" stroke-width="4" stroke="#eeeeee"/><circle class="path" cx="24" cy="24" r="22" fill="none" stroke-width="4" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke="#7cc576"/></svg></div>

$(document).ready(function($) {
    "use strict";
    // loader
    var loader = function() {
        setTimeout(function() { 
            if($('#ftco-loader').length > 0) {
                $('#ftco-loader').removeClass('show');
            }
        }, 1);
    };
    loader();

});
```

https://i.gyazo.com/fbf9068d88239986f3ed076860db4ddb.png

Comment: Compare the zIndex of the loader and navbar. You would want the loader's to be higher.

Comment: gosh... that was so obvious. Thanks mate, works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is the issue of z-index. 
Give your loader a higher z-index w.r.t. to your navbar/header.